# Grouping after using a join

Tags: sql, join, group-by

The goal is to aggregate the revenue for each cc_username. I've tried to group on cc_username, but I keep getting "not a GROUP BY expression." Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT first_name||' '||last_name as cc_username, revenue
FROM content_creators
JOIN video on video.cc_id = content_creators.cc_id
JOIN user_table on content_creators.user_id = user_table.user_id;
```

This is what I get back:

```
    cc_user     revenue
    Marco Polo  0
    Marco Polo  6800
    Mark Kalvin 99987
    Luke Travis 78923
    Luke Travis 120987
    Luke Travis 124356
```

I'm trying to group them so they are like this:

```
cc_user     revenue
Marco Polo  6800
Mark Kalvin 99987
Luke Travis 324266
```

How would you group by to aggregate the revenues for each cc_user?

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, I tried group by on cc_username but got the "not a GROUP BY expression."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this -

```
SELECT first_name||' '||last_name as cc_username, sum(revenue) revenue
FROM content_creators
JOIN video on video.cc_id = content_creators.cc_id
JOIN user_table on content_creators.user_id = user_table.user_id
group by  first_name||' '||last_name 
;
```

Comment: That worked! So, if I use group by I can't use the for a column alias?

Comment: nope. Depending on SQL engine(like impala/hive) you can use sequence like `group by 1`

Comment: @QMan5, the trick is to do all concatenation etc in a derived table, and GROUP BY its result.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you!